# Query speed drops on two "=" comparisons in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have a music database with a table for releases and the release titles. This "releases_view" gets the title/title_id and the alternative title/alternative title_id of a track. This is the code of the view:

```
SELECT
    t1.`title` AS title,
    t1.`id` AS title_id,
    t2.`title` AS title_alt,
    t2.`id` AS title_alt_id

FROM
    releases

LEFT JOIN titles t1 ON t1.`id`=`releases`.`title_id`
LEFT JOIN titles t2 ON t2.`id`=`releases`.`title_alt_id`
```

The `title_id` and `title_alt_id` fields in the joined tables are both `int(11)`, `title` and `title_alt` are varchars.

**The issue**

This query will take less than 1 ms:

```
SELECT * FROM `releases_view` WHERE title_id=12345
```

This query will take less then 1 ms, too:

```
SELECT * FROM `releases_view` WHERE title_id=12345 OR title_alt_id!=54321
```

**BUT:** This query will take 0,2 s. **It's 200 times slower!**

```
SELECT * FROM `releases_view` WHERE title_id=20956 OR title_alt_id=38849
```

As soon I have two comparisons using "=" in the WHERE clause, things really get slow (although all queries only have a couple of results).

Can you help me to understand what is going on?

**EDIT**

´EXPLAIN´ shows a USING WHERE for the title_alt_id, but I do not understand why. How can I avoid this?

** EDIT **
Here is the EXPLAIN DUMP.

```
id  select_type     table       partitions  type    possible_keys   key     key_len ref                         rows    Extra 
1   SIMPLE          releases    NULL        ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL                        76802   Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE          t1          NULL        eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY 4       db.releases.title_id        1    
1   SIMPLE          t2          NULL        eq_ref  PRIMARY         PRIMARY 4       db.releases.title_alt_id    1       Using where
```

Comment: The speed does not decrease because of the two comparisons, it decreases because of `OR` and the `JOIN`s.

Comment: @axiac, query OP pointing to doesn't have `JOIN` in place

Comment: @axiac: But example two also uses the JOIN and it has the OR. Your claim does not seem to be valid.

Comment: @Rahul. The query `SELECT`s from a `VIEW` and the view's definition uses two `LEFT JOIN`s. The view is only an alias on MySQL. Defining a view doesn't run the query used to define it. The query is merged into the query that `SELECT`s from the `VIEW`. Check the output of `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: @ArminHierstetter I don't claim anything. I provided you a hint why the last query is slow. `= OR =` is not the same as `= OR !=`.

Comment: The EXPLAIN claims a USING WHERE for the title_alt_id (which is an index). How can I avoid this?

Comment: Views are badly optimized in MySQL and a multi column index on title_id, title_alt_id might help.

Comment: Please show the DDL for the underlying tables, and the EXPLAINs for the 3 queries (ideally as a SQLFiddle) - otherwise we're guessing...

Comment: @Neville: Thanks for your help. I added the EXPLAIN for the last query. The EXPLAIN for the first two does not have the "using where".

Comment: In order to satisfy the `OR title_alt_id=38849` condition (which is, in fact, `OR t2.id = 38849`, the engine must process all the rows of `releases`. The solution is to issue separate queries to get (`title`, `title_id`) and (`title_alt`, `title_alt_id`) and match them in the client code.

Comment: @axiac: I am not sure whether I understand. So instead of one SELECT I should do two? Sorry, I am not that great in DB programming.

Comment: `SELECT t1.title AS title, t1.id AS title_id FROM releases LEFT JOIN titles t1 ON t1.id = releases.title_id WHERE title_id = 12345` and another one with `t2` and `title_alt_id = 38849`. Each of them runs as fast as the first query in the question or even faster. Then you combine their results in the client code. Or you can combine them into a `UNION` query but this is already a different topic.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

The "really slow" is because the Optimizer does not work well with `OR`.

Plan A (of the Optimizer):  Scan the entire table, evaluating the entire `OR`.

Plan B:  "Index Merge Union" could be used for `title_id = 20956 OR title_alt_id = 38849` *if* you have separate indexes in `title_id` and `title_alt_id`:  use each index to get two lists of `PRIMARY KEYs` and "merge" the lists, then reach into the table to get `*`.  Multiple steps, not cheap.  So Plan B is rarely used.

`title_id = 12345 OR title_alt_id != 54321` is a mystery, since it should return most of the table.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT...`.

`LEFT JOIN` (as opposed to `JOIN`) needs to assume that the row may be missing in the 'right' table.